# How can I show three elements per page in a carousel?

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to modify this carousel (https://codepen.io/ancaspatariu/pen/WpQYOP) in order to insert it in a book retail website. What I'm trying to achieve is to show three book covers for each "slide" of the carousel. This is my code now, I added the display: inline-block property but it still shows one cover per slide.
The code is longer, but I will show you just the parts regarding the images carousel layout.

**HTML**

```
<div>
<div class="carousel">
<ul class="slides">
<input type="radio" name="radio-buttons" id="img-1" checked />
  <li class="slide-container">
  <div class="slide-image">
  <img src="Bookaholic/img/DearData_US_jacket.jpeg" >
  </div>
  <div class="slide-image">
  <img src="Bookaholic/img/DearData_US_jacket.jpeg" >
  </div>
```

**CSS**

```
ul.slides {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  height: 600px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  list-style: none;
}

.slide-container { 
  display: inline-block; 
  white-space: nowrap;
  width:1400px;
}

.slide-image {
  display: inherit;
  position: absolute;
  bottom:80%;
  left:20%;
  width: 20%;
  height: 60%;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all .7s ease-in-out;
}  

.slide-image img {
  width: 20%;
  min-width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

[image]

Comment: You would need to put three images in each slide, however I would advise against using this as it has invalid html - inputs cannot be a child of ul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the example on [CodePen](https://codepen.io/ancaspatariu/pen/WpQYOP) that you quoted, to modify it to include 3 images in each slide, you just need to add 2 more images in each `div.slide-image`, for example:

```
<div class="slide-image">
  <img src="img1.jpg">
  <img src="img2.jpg">
  <img src="img3.jpg">
  ...
```

then change the css of those images to:

```
.slide-image img {
  width: 33.333%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: It was that easy. Unfortunately I've just started with HTML and CSS. Thanks to you and everyone that replied!

Answer (score 1):

You can use plugin to do so:
Slick Carousel is an awesome one, Check out the link https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Fully-Responsive-Flexible-jQuery-Carousel-Plugin-slick/

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be accomplished by using flexbox or grid. This is a quick example that I've prepared to show you how to use flexbox. The main property would be "Flex basis" I would need more of your code to be able to reproduce it for your use case:

"carrusel__wrapper" would be your slide_container and "item" your slide_image.

```
<div class="carrusel__wrapper">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.carrusel__wrapper{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

.item{
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 0 10px;
}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ROKrdN

I can prepare a better example if you provide me with a cleaner code.